# When are whitespace significant in translation phases 5 and 6 in C language?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

To recap, the phases 5-7 are described in the standard:

> 5. Each source character set member and escape sequence in character constants and string literals is converted to the corresponding member
>      of the execution character set; if there is no corresponding member,
>      it is converted to an implementation- defined member other than the
>      null (wide) character. 7)
> 6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.
> 7. White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant. Each preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting
>      tokens are syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a
>      translation unit.

Now I agree that whites-space characters are no longer significant at phase 7, but couldn't one get rid of them already after phase 4? Is there an example where this would make a difference?

Of course it should be realized that removing white-space characters separating **tokens** doesn't work at this stage as the data after phase 4 consists of **preprocessing tokens**. The idea is to get rid of spaces separating preprocessing tokens at an earlier stage.

Comment: I don't see a programming problem we can help you with. This is perhaps a better question on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), or maybe [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compilers)

Comment: @icabod This question fits the [tag:language-lawyer] tag perfectly, so it's definitely on-topic even if there's no code.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is 8 years late, but the only other answer is incorrect, so I'm leaving this in case anyone else Googles the same question and finds this post. I will be referencing [N3096](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf), the latest public working draft of the C standard (as of the writing of this answer).

---

The only mention of the significance of white-space separating preprocessing tokens, other than in § 5.1.1.2 p1 when the translation phases are first described, is § 6.4 p3:

> As described in 6.10, in certain circumstances during translation phase 4, white space (or the absence thereof) serves as more than preprocessing token separation. White space may appear within a preprocessing token only as part of a header name or between the quotation characters in a character constant or string literal.

As this paragraph indicates (and as you mention), white-space separating tokens is significant during phase 4 in order to differentiate `#define X (a, b)` and `#define X(a, b)` (§ 6.10.4 p10) and, in the case of new-lines, to terminate preprocessing directives (§ 6.10 p2).

In my opinion, this wording implies that white-space separating tokens is only significant during phase 4. Otherwise, I would expect it to say, e.g., "in certain circumstances *such as* during translation phase 4."

I think the placement of this instruction in phase 7 rather than 5 is a logical grouping on the part of the editor, as phases 5 and 6 focus on character constants and string literals and phase 7 is the next major change in the representation of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this source code

```
char* str = "some text"   " with spaces";
```

In phase 5 this is converted to these tokens (one token per line):

```
char
*
str
=
"some text"    
" with spaces"
```

Here matter the spaces in "some text" and " with spaces".

Afterwards all spacees **between tokens** (see above) are ignored.

If you remove whitespace before step 5 you get other string literals like "sometext"

Comment: However, even before step 5 the data consists of preprocessing tokens, and that's important as you otherwise couldn't replace escape sequences within strings. If you remove the spaces between preprocessing tokens this would not happen. Also note in phase 7 the whitespace is removed **before** preprocessing tokens are converted into tokens (no conversion into tokens are done in phase 5).

Comment: This is wrong. A string literal is a single pp token and white space removal can't turn "some text" into "sometext".